# How to fix react router sending a 404 page whenever css requests a font file?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, fonts, react-router

I'm trying to do global font faces for my app and so in the `index.jsx` I import `fonts.css` which contains:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Extrabold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
}
```

In the chrome dev tools, I see that it's trying to get the font, but it returns html instead of the font it actually wants. This results in the font not being able to be decoded.

I'm pretty sure this is a result of my use of react-router-dom having a 404 route and webpack having some kind of issue.

This seems like such a trivial thing to do but it's been taking me the past hour and a half and I've gotten nowhere. Let me know if I need to be more clear. Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: i think its better that  you add your `fonts.css`  to `index.html` in public folder like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/fonts.css" />` have you test that?

Comment: @RezaHashemi When I do that, the dev tools in Chrome doesn't even show that the browser even tries to get the font file